# How to Troubleshoot Playground CIFilter Error Message

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cifilter, xcode9.1

The code below should run fine: I didn't write it!  :-)

I tried running some Swift Playground code by Simon J. Gladman (https://github.com/FlexMonkey) that corresponds to Chapter 8, "Warp Kernels," in his book, Core Image for Swift. As he wrote this code in Xcode 7.2 and I'm running it in Xcode 9.1, I had to update it in several places, which in most cases amounted to merely accepting the error handler's (or whatever it's called's) suggestions. After doing that, the following, more serious sounding message appeared:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
>   The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread >return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Other than knowing that SIGABRT stands for "signal abort," I have no idea what it means or, more importantly, how to trouble shoot the error. (I'm still just learning Swift and Cocoa/Cocoa Touch. . . .) Suggestions would be appreciated.

```
//: ## Barrel Distortion Warp Filter

import UIKit
import CoreImage

//: ### Warp Kernel

class CRTWarpFilter: CIFilter
{
    var inputImage: CIImage?
    var bend: CGFloat = 3.2

    let crtWarpKernel = CIWarpKernel(source:
        "kernel vec2 crtWarp(vec2 extent, float bend)" +
            "{" +
            "   vec2 coord = ((destCoord() / extent) - 0.5) * 2.0;" +

            "   coord.x *= 1.0 + pow((abs(coord.y) / bend), 2.0);" +
            "   coord.y *= 1.0 + pow((abs(coord.x) / bend), 2.0);" +

            "   coord  = ((coord / 2.0) + 0.5) * extent;" +

            "   return coord;" +
        "}"
    )

    override var outputImage: CIImage!
    {
        if let inputImage = inputImage, let crtWarpKernel = crtWarpKernel
        {
            let arguments = [CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.size.width,
                                      y: inputImage.extent.size.height),
                             bend] as [Any]

            let extent = inputImage.extent

            return crtWarpKernel.apply(extent: extent,
                                       roiCallback:
                                           {(index, rect) in return rect},
                                       image: inputImage,
                                       arguments: arguments)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let ciContext = CIContext()

func imageFromCIImage(source: CIImage) -> UIImage
{
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(source, from: source.extent)

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}

//: ### Swift Implementation of barrel warp kernel

//: `x` and `y` are pixel coordinates
let x = 65.0
let y = 55.0

//: `width` and `height` are extent
let width = 900.0
let height = 300.0

//: `crtWarpKernel` mechanics in Swift
var coordX = ((x / width) - 0.5) * 2.0
var coordY = ((y / height) - 0.5) * 2.0

coordX *= 1 + pow((abs(coordY) / 3.2), 2.0)
coordY *= 1 + pow((abs(coordX) / 3.2), 2.0)

coordX  = ((coordX / 2.0) + 0.5) * width
coordY  = ((coordY / 2.0) + 0.5) * height

// ----

let backgroundImage = CIFilter(name: "CICheckerboardGenerator",
                               withInputParameters: [
                                "inputColor0":
                                    CIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1),
                                "inputColor1":
                                    CIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15),
                                "inputCenter": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0),
                                "inputWidth": 50])!
    .outputImage!.cropped(to: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1,
                                     width: width - 2,
                                     height: height - 2))
    .composited(over: CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0)))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
                        size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))

let blueBox = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 0.7))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: coordX - 5, y: coordY - 5),
                        size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))

let redBox = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x - 5, y: y - 5),
                        size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))

let warpFilter = CRTWarpFilter()

warpFilter.inputImage = backgroundImage

let composite = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing",
                         withInputParameters: [
                            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: warpFilter.outputImage,
                            kCIInputImageKey: blueBox])!
    .outputImage!
    .applyingFilter("CIAdditionCompositing",
                    parameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: redBox])

let result = composite
```

Comment: it's just an exception being thrown without caught... You need to find out (with log prints maybe?) in which line it occurs and because of what.. Maybe it's an optional being forced to unwrap but with a nil value? (You have a lot of ! in your code)

Comment: I don't use playground much at all. You could quickly set up an Xcode project and execute it. I don't think you get the console, which should point you any issues with your kernel code. Also, if something is nil you probably with stop execution close to where you can find out what it is. Now, the *reason* for the `nil` can be anything, including a misspelled key or filter name. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playground does not like that `inputImage` is not declared as @objc. If you change this:

```
class CRTWarpFilter: CIFilter
{
    var inputImage: CIImage?
```

To this:

```
class CRTWarpFilter: CIFilter
{
    @objc var inputImage: CIImage?
```

It's going to work fine.

Here's your code updated to `Xcode 11` and `Swift 5`

```
//: ## Barrel Distortion Warp Filter

import UIKit
import CoreImage

//: ### Warp Kernel

class CRTWarpFilter: CIFilter
{
    @objc var inputImage: CIImage?
    var bend: CGFloat = 3.2

    let crtWarpKernel = CIWarpKernel(source: """
        kernel vec2 crtWarp(vec2 extent, float bend)
        {
           vec2 coord = ((destCoord() / extent) - 0.5) * 2.0;

           coord.x *= 1.0 + pow((abs(coord.y) / bend), 2.0);
           coord.y *= 1.0 + pow((abs(coord.x) / bend), 2.0);

           coord  = ((coord / 2.0) + 0.5) * extent;

           return coord;
        }
    """)

    override var outputImage: CIImage?
    {
        if let inputImage = inputImage, let crtWarpKernel = crtWarpKernel
        {
            let arguments = [CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.size.width,
                                      y: inputImage.extent.size.height),
                             bend] as [Any]

            let extent = inputImage.extent

            return crtWarpKernel.apply(extent: extent,
                                       roiCallback:
                {(index, rect) in return rect},
                                       image: inputImage,
                                       arguments: arguments)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let ciContext = CIContext()

func imageFromCIImage(source: CIImage) -> UIImage
{
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(source, from: source.extent)

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}

//: ### Swift Implementation of barrel warp kernel

//: `x` and `y` are pixel coordinates
let x = 65.0
let y = 55.0

//: `width` and `height` are extent
let width = 900.0
let height = 300.0

//: `crtWarpKernel` mechanics in Swift
var coordX = ((x / width) - 0.5) * 2.0
var coordY = ((y / height) - 0.5) * 2.0

coordX *= 1 + pow((abs(coordY) / 3.2), 2.0)
coordY *= 1 + pow((abs(coordX) / 3.2), 2.0)

coordX  = ((coordX / 2.0) + 0.5) * width
coordY  = ((coordY / 2.0) + 0.5) * height

// ----

let backgroundImage = CIFilter(name: "CICheckerboardGenerator",
                               parameters: [
                                "inputColor0":
                                    CIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1),
                                "inputColor1":
                                    CIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15),
                                "inputCenter": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0),
                                "inputWidth": 50])!
    .outputImage!.cropped(to: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1,
                                     width: width - 2,
                                     height: height - 2))
    .composited(over: CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0)))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
                        size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))

let blueBox = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 0.7))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: coordX - 5, y: coordY - 5),
                        size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))

let redBox = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7))
    .cropped(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x - 5, y: y - 5),
                        size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))

let warpFilter = CRTWarpFilter()
warpFilter.inputImage = backgroundImage

let composite = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing",
                         parameters: [
                            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: warpFilter.outputImage,
                            kCIInputImageKey: blueBox])!
    .outputImage!
    .applyingFilter("CIAdditionCompositing",
                    parameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: redBox])

let result = composite
```

Comment: Thanks, Dannie, for the thorough reply. Since asking my question nearly two years ago, I discovered and changed to using SpriteKit, which was also easier to implement. In any case, I hope others will benefit from your help.